# ServiceStack.Text model.ToCsv() not wrapping output properties in quotes

Tags: c#, csv, servicestack

Using [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) to output CSV files from a C# console application. It generates the output for all of the public properties on the model. The output generated does not output the properties wrapped in quotes, which is a client requirement.

```
CsvConfig.Reset();
CsvConfig.ItemDelimiterString = JsWriter.QuoteString;
workingFile.Write(modelToWrite.ToCsv());
```

Looking at the documentation, I don't see any explicit references that says "do this to wrap output properties in quotes". I found this:

> CSV escaping Any string with any of the following characters: []{},"
>   is escaped using CSV-style escaping where the value is wrapped in
>   double quotes, e.g:
>
> new MyClass { Name = "Me, Junior" } is serialized as:
>
> {Name:"Me, Junior"}

I set a property with a default value of `"[MSI]"` and it did generate the CSV wrapping [MSI] in double quotes.

My requirement is to wrap each output property value in quotes but I am not seeing a setting to force it do that.

Can you help me get the output properties wrapped in double quotes?

Comment: General csv rules ([rfc4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)) indeed specify that quotes are _only_ required if the content contains quotes or split characters. If the client requirements are different than what `ServiceStack.Text` does, your simplest solution is to just write it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, @Nyerguds. I was afraid of that. I appreciate the response. If you add this as an answer, I will mark it as such.

Comment: Okay, I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general standard for csv is [rfc4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), and it indeed specifies that quotes are only required if the content contains quotes or split characters.

If the client requirements are different than what `ServiceStack.Text` does, your simplest solution is to just write a CSV writer yourself. You just need to escape the values according to the given rules.

This isn't really hard, of course. In your case, from the the information you gave, it'd probably just be something like this:

```
public static String GetAsCsvField(String input)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        return "\"\""
    return "\"" + input.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\""
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per @Nyerguds comment, CSV fields only needs to be quoted if the field contains escape characters which is the behavior of ServiceStack.Text and there’s no configuration to force quotes when they’re not needed.

All CSV readers should be able to parse unquoted fields given it’s the most common format used for CSV fields.

Comment: Unfortunately, "All CSV readers should" has no basis in reality. When you're a programmer, "All customers have weird and horrible specs and you just have to deal with it" is much closer to the truth.

Comment: @Nyerguds All CSV parsers should handle the most common CSV format otherwise they’re not CSV parsers. Having horrible specs means parsers should be more tolerant not incapable of handling the most basic format

Comment: As I said, that statement is irrelevant, since in real-life situations, you get plenty of cases where the other side will simply _not_ follow these "most common" specs, and you as programmer are asked to write something that simply _works for them_.

Comment: A spec isn’t irrelevant, it’s exactly what allows conforming impls to interoperate. Like I said it’s the most common format for a CSV field, a library that’s incapable of parsing it can’t call itself a CSV parser, it would be useless in parsing anything CSV in which case you should make a custom serializer in dealing with whatever format it expects cause it’s not CSV.

Comment: A spec _is_ irrelevant if it's not the spec that the customer is using. As I said, and *as is the case in this question right here,* the specs you get in real life are very often _not_ the "most common" ones. The program at the other side of the pipeline will have its _own_ specs, and there's not a thing you can do about that from your side. Sure you can complain... but then they'll just find someone else that _will_ conform to it, and you **lose a customer.**

Comment: Do note... rfc4180 is _not_ a 'specification' of "the RTF format". The use of RTF is _much_ older than rfc4180, and the document is merely a 'Request for Comments'; in other words, in this case, it is a _recommendation_. No one has any obligation to follow it, and RTF processing systems that don't follow it are **not wrong**.

Comment: Exactly your customer isn’t following the spec so they’re not conforming to CSV so this question shouldn’t be about CSV.  It should be about how I can I generate the format my customer wants which as I said is to create a custom serializer that emits the format your customer needs. Spec’s are very important for computational data transfer, but your client isn’t using it so this question shouldn’t be about CSV which by definition is a format that conforms to the spec. Your point about RFCs is misunderstood, it is a spec, you never have to follow it but you shouldn’t be claiming that you are.

Comment: They never claimed that. They claim to use CSV, which is still 100% correct even if not following rfc4180. You can conform to rfc4180, but there is no such thing as "conforming to CSV". Because the only thing "CSV" means is "comma separated values".

Comment: If it’s not following the spec than by definition they can’t claim their 100% using CSV.

Comment: RFC4180 opening statement: "**This memo provides information for the Internet community.  It does not specify an Internet standard of any kind.**" And later on: "**This section documents the format that seems to be followed by most implementations:**". Not specs. Not a standard. Just the _documenting_ of _a_ commonly used CSV format.

Comment: @Nyerguds Are you seriously kidding? Is this the first time you've seen an RFC?[RFC's are specs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RFCs) irrespective if they have been ratified by a standards body or not. HTTP, FTP, DNS, DHCP are all RFC's, you can't claim you conform to any of those protocols unless you conform to the RFC which defines it. Likewise you're not conforming to CSV unless you conform rfc4180 which is what defines CSV and by definition what it is.

Comment: Specs, yes. Of 'a' usable type of CSV. Standards, though? No. The RFC itself _specifically states_ that it isn't. And the page on RFCs itself states that "the IETF adopts _some_ of the proposals published as RFCs as Internet Standards", but for CSV **this has never happened**. Simple truth is, there _are no_ 'hard' specs for CSV. Just a format description of, as the RFC _specifically_ states, a _commonly used type_.

Comment: @Nyerguds I'm going to end it here, it's not worth arguing this irrelevant point further and agree to disagree.